# Базы Данных Имена индексов inner join Mysql SQl

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Есть таблица в таблице есть индексы как мне узнать имена этих индексов.
Кон[image: Если конкретней мне нужно запросить все данные из таблицы 'transits' только что бы вместо полей city_country_in, city_country_out, profile_id были не их id(первичные ключи а имена(поля name))]

Comment: Имена индексов можно посмотреть в коде создания таблицы (`SHOW CREATE TABLE`). Есть ещё несколько вариантов получения той же информации...

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
select i.name from information_schema.innodb_sys_indexes I 
join information_schema.innodb_sys_tables t 
    on t.table_id=i.table_id
    where t.name='имяБазы/имяТаблицы';
```

Comment: Ну это при условии, что у него именно InnoDB-таблицы.